# how do I select rows from pandas df without returning False values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I have a df and I need to select rows based on some conditions in multiple columns.

Here is what I have

```
import pandas as pd
dat = [('p','q', 5), ('k','j', 2), ('p','-', 5), ('-','p', 4), ('q','pkjq', 3), ('pkjq','q', 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
df_dat = df[(df[['a','b']].isin(['k','p','q','j']) & df['c'] > 3)] | df[(~df[['a','b']].isin(['k','p','q','j']) & df['c'] > 2 )]
```

Expected result = [('p','q', 5), ('p','-', 5), ('-','p', 4), ('q','pkjq', 3)]

Result I am getting is an all false dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have the complicate condition I recommend, make the condition outside the slice

```
cond1 = df[['a','b']].isin(['k','p','q','j']).any(1) & df['c'].gt(3)
cond2 = (~df[['a','b']].isin(['k','p','q','j'])).any(1) & df['c'].gt(2)

out = df.loc[cond1 | cond2]
Out[305]: 
   a     b  c
0  p     q  5
2  p     -  5
3  -     p  4
4  q  pkjq  3
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason of using `df.loc` instead of just using `df[cond1 | cond2]`? Thanks...

Comment: right. I did not think about that. Thank you

Comment: @TheExile using `.loc` is preferred because it is less ambiguous to the reader as bare `[]` could refer to columns or rows. In the case where the number of columns and the number of rows are equally, it get really ambiguous.

Comment: what happens if it throws a NoneType object is not subcriptable? does that mean there are null or none values? how will such cases be handle in the above?